# Merge multiple rows in one column on an index value

Tags: python, pandas

After using `str.extractall()`, I have a multi-level dataframe that looks like this:

```
id  match  Names
1   0      Rob Corddry
    1      Craig Robinson
    2      Clark Duke
...
1   23     Kisha Sierra
2   0      Anne Hathaway
    1      Julie Andrews
...
```

I want a series or dictionary that looks like this with all the names in a single row that share the same "id":

```
id  Names
1   Rob Corddry, Craig Robinson, Clark Duke ... Kisha Sierra     
2   Anne Hathaway, Julie Andrews ...
```

I want to merge this series/dict back into the dataframe I extracted it from on the index `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `groupby` `agg` + `join`

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Wen-Ben